# automating a database backup, restore and stored proc call

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

How do I create a process that will:

- backup Database A restore it as Database X (needs to be definable)
- then run a stored procedure against Database X.
- shrink and truncate its log file.

Anybody got ideas?  Could it be a stored proc on the Master db?

The whole process takes hours and is taking me away from valuable time.

Comment: Fyi, don't include the log file in the back-up since you're going to axe it anyway :)

Comment: Yes its a sql server

Comment: @Kris  how do i not include the log in the backup.. Mostly the log problem comes from all the transactions that happen after i restore in the stored procedure..

Comment: alter database [database name] set recovery simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Database A]
TO DISK = 'C:\Temp\DatabaseA.bak' WITH FORMAT
GO
use master
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [Database X]
FROM  DISK = N'C:\Temp\DatabaseA.bak'
,  MOVE N'DataFile' TO N'C:\Foo\DatabaseX.mdf'
,  MOVE N'LogFile' TO N'C:\Bar\DatabaseX.ldf'
,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10

GO
use [Database X]
GO
exec StoredProcedureName...
GO
use master
GO
DBCC ShrinkDatabase( [Database X] )
```

Comment: no joke its that easy?  Anyway i can define where log and mdf files go?

Comment: @Rico - Of course. The paths I used were merely for demonstration purposes. On the restore command, you can add a MOVE directive that will tell it where to put the mdf and ldf files. Btw, given your post, I assumed this was SQL Server.

Comment: @Rico - I updated my answer to show you what it would look like to place the mdf and ldf files. Obviously, you will need to know the name of the files in the database (in my example I used DataFile and LogFile) which you can get by looking at the properties of the database in Management Studio.

Comment: @Thomas  Perfect thanks man..  ima get this to good use immediately

Comment: Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx - probably you want to tweak the expiration and compression and other settings